# What is the command for Selenium to click on "Don't allow" when IPhone asks for the location?

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, saucelabs

I run tests with Selenium to test a website using the Saucelabs service. The Website asks the browsers to use their location. My tests ignore those questions and run in most browsers quite well. But when it comes to IPhone IOS 7.1 I don't get around the popup "Safari would like to use your current location".

How do I click the button "Don't allow" using Selenium for php? Can I get this element by CSS-Selector or ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. To click on the button "Don't allow" I have to use:

```
$this->dismissAlert();
```

In case I want to confirm:

```
$this->acceptAlert()
```

Both of them come out from the extension "PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase".